# FormsAuthentication.SignOut() not working after changing the CookieDomain

Tags: c#, forms-authentication

In the web.config, we had the following:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/login" timeout="43200" slidingExpiration="true" name=".PX" />
</authentication>
```

We have since updated it to this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/login" timeout="43200" slidingExpiration="true" name=".PX" enableCrossAppRedirects="true" domain="[websitename].com" />
</authentication>
```

The problem is, users who are *already logged in* are no longer signed out when we call `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()`.

Instead of just callign `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()`, I now do the following, but it still isn't signing out currently logged in users:

```
private static void SignOut(HttpContextBase context)
{
    RemoveCookie(context, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath, FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain, true);
    RemoveCookie(context, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath, FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain, false);
    RemoveCookie(context, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath, null, true);
    RemoveCookie(context, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath, null, false);

    // clear cookies server side
    context.Request.Cookies.Clear();

    context.Session.Abandon();
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
}

private static void RemoveCookie(HttpContextBase context, string name, string path, string domain, bool httpOnly)
{
    context.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie(name, "NoCookie")
    {
        Path = path,
        Domain = domain,
        Secure = false,
        Shareable = false,
        HttpOnly = httpOnly,
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d)
    });
}
```

Comment: To "logoff", you have to set an old expiration date, something like this: `var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, "NoCookie"); cookie.Expires = new DateTime(1999, 1, 1); context.Response.Cookies.Remove(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName); context.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `FormsAuthentication.SignOut()` there is a call the *removes* all of the previous cookies from the Response: `context.Response.Cookies.RemoveCookie(FormsCookieName);` (https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/Security/FormsAuthentication.cs#L421)

Changing the order of everything seems to fix the issue:

```
private static void SignOut(HttpContextBase context)
{
    context.Session.Abandon();
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

    RemoveCookie(context, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath, FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain, true);
    RemoveCookie(context, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath, FormsAuthentication.CookieDomain, false);
    RemoveCookie(context, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath, null, true);
    RemoveCookie(context, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath, null, false);

    // clear cookies server side
    context.Request.Cookies.Clear();
}
```